# I need to print out hyper parameters and parameters from a machine learning model in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I need to print out Tensorflow models parameters and hyper-parameters.Below is the code I am using and when I try to print out the model I am only getting the model storage location. I also tried sklearn wrapper for Tensorflow with GridSearchCv but I am getting some errors. I can't try Hyperparams as it is deprecated in Tensorflow2.0.0 and I am using Tensorflow 2.0 and python 3.7

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32,input_shape=(3,)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x, y, batch_size=5, epochs=10)
print(model)

Error
<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x000001823B68BDD8>
```

Comment: Try `model.summary()`

Comment: model .summary() is giving me the layers and the number of trainable parameters but not the value of those parameters are

Comment: The value of the parameters (I assume you mean weights?) aren't hyperparameters, they're just regular old parameters.

Comment: By parameters I mean loss, optimizer, epochs, batch_size, metrics and few other parameters not weights

Comment: Ahh, okay. When you call `model.fit(...)`, you want to assign the results to something (`history = model.fit(...)`). This saves a training history where you can access the metrics you tell it to track in `metrics=`. Not sure about optimizer.

Comment: yes similar to sklearn get_params() method

Comment: Unfortunately (history = model.fit(...)) is just giving me the location of model it is stored. No information  about the parameters at all

Comment: The history is an object, not a value. You need to access its attributes.

Answer (score 4):

one option is  `model.get_config()`  that gives you a JSON list

Comment: try to refrain from `maybe`, only write answers

Answer (score 3):

Elaborating the suggestions mentioned in the comment and providing the solution below.

From the question and comments, I understand that you have built a Model, trained it and you want to access `Parameters/Metrics/Loss` like `loss`, `epochs`, `batch_size`, `metrics`, etc..

For getting those values, as mentioned in the comments, assign the `results` of `model.fit` to a variable, say `history`, as shown below

```
history = model.fit(x = Train_Generator, shuffle=True, epochs = 3, steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch,
          validation_data = Val_Generator, validation_steps = validation_steps
                   )
```

All the values which we need will be present in `history.history`:

```
print(history.history)
```

Output of the above command is :

```
{'loss': [0.7191072106361389, 0.6968516707420349, 0.7295272946357727],
 'acc': [0.5074999928474426, 0.531499981880188, 0.5584999918937683],
 'val_loss': [4.8877854347229, 5.5809173583984375, 58.02076721191406],
 'val_acc': [0.5, 0.49900001287460327, 0.5090000033378601]}
```

As seen above, since the Training was done for 3 `Epochs`, there are 3 Values corresponding to `Training Loss`, `Training Accuracy`, `Validation Loss` and `Validation Accuracy`.

We shall now print the values which we want:

```
print('Number of Epochs are ', len(history.history['loss']))
print("Training Loss is ", history.history['loss'])
print("Validation Loss is ", history.history['val_loss'])
print("Training Accuracy is ", history.history['acc'])
print("Validation Accuracy is ", history.history['val_acc'])
```

Output of the above `print` statements are shown below:

```
Number of Epochs are  3
Training Loss is  [0.7191072106361389, 0.6968516707420349, 0.7295272946357727]
Validation Loss is  [4.8877854347229, 5.5809173583984375, 58.02076721191406]
Training Accuracy is  [0.5074999928474426, 0.531499981880188, 0.5584999918937683]
Validation Accuracy is  [0.5, 0.49900001287460327, 0.5090000033378601]
```

We can also plot the beautiful plots of the above Metrics/Values using the Code below:

```
training_acc = history.history['acc']
val_acc = history.history['val_acc']
training_loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

Number_Of_Epochs = range(1, len(history.history['acc']) + 1)

plt.plot(Number_Of_Epochs, training_acc, color = 'green', marker = '*', label = 'Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(Number_Of_Epochs, val_acc, color = 'blue', marker = 'o', label = 'Validation Accuracy')
plt.title('Training Accuracy and Validation Accuracy Vs Epochs')
plt.legend()
plt.figure()

plt.plot(Number_Of_Epochs, training_loss, color = 'green', marker = '*', label = 'Training Loss')
plt.plot(Number_Of_Epochs, val_loss, color = 'blue', marker = 'o', label = 'Validation Loss')
plt.title('Training Loss and Validation Loss Vs Epochs')
plt.legend()
plt.figure()
```

Plots are shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Plot of Accuracy and Loss]

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!